# Non-linear parametric equation zeros analytical formula

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, parametric

As in the title, I have to find the zeros of a non-linear parametric equation with several parameters as functions of the parameters themselves. I tried using "Solve" in Mathematica and "solve" / "solveset" in Python Sympy.
Sympy returns the empty set while even Mathematica crushed.
Do you have any suggestion for different packages, functions or software?

$$( A + B)\cdot \frac{- C + e^{-\frac{D-E}{C}}\cdot(C + D - E)}{(D-E)^2} +B\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{D-E}{C}}}{C}$$

subject to the following constraint:
$A + B > 0$;
$ C >0$;
$E \ge 0$;
$  D > E$.

I have to solve for $D$ and the problem is that it is not only in the exponential, therefore symbolic engines cannot solve for it.
Any solutions?

That is already a first derivative, but we need also to consider the second derivative so clearly, we have to derivate that again. I tried with simpler functions involving the exponential and our software can provide a solution based on the Lambert W function, but for my case they cannot reach to a solution. Do you think that is just matter of computational power or there is no analyical solution?

Comment: @IV_ Yes, sure it would be helpuful because not being a mathematician I struggle a bit with complex analysis. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please clarify what your first derivative is and what you want to differentiate a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(A+B)\left(\frac{-C+e^{-\frac{(D-E)}{C}}(C+D-E)}{(D-E)^2}+\frac{Be^{-\frac{(D-E)}{C}}}{C}\right)=0$$
$D\to E-Cx$:
$$(A+B)\frac{-C+(C+Cx)e^x}{C^2x^2}+\frac{Be^x}{C^2}=0$$
$$-ACxe^x-BCxe^x+Bx^2e^x+ACe^x+BCe^x-AC-BC=0\tag{1}$$

We see, your equation can be transformed into a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^x$), without a univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $D$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We see, for algebraic $A,B,C$, equation (1) is an irreducible algebraic equation of $x$ and $e^x$ simultaneously. According to the theorems in Lin 1983 and Chow 1999, such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively if [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true.

$$-(A+B)C+((A+B)C-(A+B)Cx+Bx^2)e^x=0$$
$$e^x=\frac{(A+B)C}{(A+B)C-(A+B)Cx+Bx^2}$$
$$\frac{(A+B)C-(A+B)Cx+Bx^2}{(A+B)C}e^x=1$$
$$((A+B)C-(A+B)Cx+Bx^2)e^x=(A+B)C\tag{2}$$

We see, because equation (2) is a polynomial equation of $e^x$, $x$ and $x^2$, the equation is not in a form for applying Lambert W, but Generalized Lambert W.

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C-\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C+\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B}\right)e^x=(A+B)C$$
$$x=W\left(^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C-\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B},\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C+\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B}}_{ };(A+B)C\right)$$
$$D=E-C\ W\left(^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C-\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B},\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A+B)C+\sqrt{(A+B)C((A+B)C-4B)C}}{B}}_{ };(A+B)C\right)$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $D$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $D$.
$\ $

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)